# Reset Switch Wiring on STM32

Tags: switches, stm32

I want to wire a reset switch for my STM32F0 microcontroller. The datasheet suggests the following external circuity to do so:

[image]

Connected to the NRST pin is a 0.1uF capacitor and the reset switch. A pullup resistor is included internally in the microcontroller. However, when the switch is pressed won't it short circuit the capacitor and thus cause large current pulses/ interference? (Problems similar to what was found here: https://forums.parallax.com/discussion/110594/button-pull-up-resistor-reset-problem). Should I wire the circuit like what was shown in the datasheet or add a current limiting resistor?

Comment: You won't get much of a transient with a 100 nF cap.

Comment: https://youtu.be/rphm4FCKlt0?t=24

Comment: Just use a basic 0.1µF (100nF) cap. Nothing fancy, no polypropylene or NPO ceramic. Could put the cap right on the switch - then the (tiny) current spike when closed is localized to the switch itself and the loop area is kept as short as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, shorting a capacitor with a button does cause a large pulse of current. In fact, AVR hardware design guide suggests that when a push button with contact bounce and reset capacitor is combined with stray inductance from wires and PCB traces, the surge voltages can be out of specs for the reset pin and thus a 330R series resistor is recommended. Also the maximum current rating of a simple tactile switch may easily be exceeded.

A 330 ohm resistor limits the surge current to 10mA which is usually below maximum rating and above minimum wetting current rating to keep contacts clean. STM32 chips seem to have diode protection to positive supply voltage as well so it may not absolutely require a series resistor but nevertheless it is a good design choice to include it.

As the reset button is almost never required on a final product, the resistor plays very little role and sometimes even the switch is removed from the final product.